# How can I get the iCloud for Windows app to show my photos as JPG instead of HEIC?

Tags: icloud, windows, photos

I have well over 10,000 photos in iCloud, and I want to download them as JPG files instead of HEIC. When I login to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/) in a web browser, it gives me options to download my photos as HEIC or JPG:

[image]

The problem with the iCloud web interface is that it only lets you download 1000 photos at a time. I would like to download all my photos as JPG files in a single download.

So I installed Apple's [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/103232) app on my Windows PC. The app has no limitation on how many photos you can download at once from iCloud (or if it does have a limit, it is well over 10000).

The iCloud for Windows app displays all your iCloud photos (even if you haven't downloaded them) under `C:\Users\username\Pictures\iCloud Photos\Photos`. The problem is that it shows all my iCloud photos as HEIC files, so that means I can only download them as HEIC. Under the iCloud for Windows app's Photo Settings, there is a `Download High-Efficiency format photos and videos` option that is checked and grayed out. Even though it is grayed out, it still lets me uncheck it, but after I close the settings window and re-open it, that option is still checked.

[image]

Is there any way to have the iCloud for Windows app allow me to download my iCloud photos as JPG instead of HEIC files?